# Is it not possible to have password reset feature in Bitcoin Core Wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, bitcoin-core-development, wallet-recovery, bitcoin-development

I would like to know why there is no feature to retrieve forgot password or reset with a new password ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Because it could be used by anyone with access to your device. You may as well have no passphrase and leave the wallet completely unprotected.

Businesses can offer a password reset for an account because they have details of their customers including ways to weakly check identity. Bitcoin core, by design, is not a business, has no lists of customers and no ways to verify their identity.

It is important that developers do not have any back door access to everyone else's money.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense to me. Can't we have security questions at least ?

Comment: You may be able to find a [password manager](https://www.google.com/search?q=password+manager) with the features you desire. A master password to retrieve your subsequently forgotten Bitcoin Core wallet-passphrase and some security questions to recover or reset a forgotten master password.